# KeyError at / 'daily'

Tags: python, django, backend, keyerror

> current_weather_url =
> 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid={}'
>
> forecast_url =
> 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/onecall?lat={}&lon={}&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid={}'

```py
def fetch_weather_and_forecast(city, api_key, current_weather_url, forecast_url):
    response = requests.get(current_weather_url.format(city, api_key)).json()
    lat, lon = response['coord']['lat'], response['coord']['lon']
    forecast_response = requests.get(forecast_url.format(lat, lon, api_key)).json()

    weather_data = {
        'city': city,
        'temperature': round(response['main']['temp'] - 273.15, 2),
        'description': response['weather'][0]['description'],
        'icon': response['weather'][0]['icon'],
    }

    daily_forecasts = []
    for daily_data in forecast_response['daily'][:5]:
        daily_forecasts.append({
            'day': datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(daily_data['dt']).strftime('%A'),
            'min_temp': round(daily_data['temp']['min'] - 273.15, 2),
            'max_temp': round(daily_data['temp']['max'] - 273.15, 2),
            'description': daily_data['weather'][0]['description'],
            'icon': daily_data['weather'][0]['icon'],
        })

    return weather_data, daily_forecasts
```

**This is the forecast response that I get:**

```json
forecast_response   
{'cod': 401,
 'message': 'Invalid API key. Please see '
            'https://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info.'}
```

Actually I am creating a weather app where I used API from https://home.openweathermap.org/
but while using the forecast URL in the above function in the for loop for daily_forecasts it says that:

> >>>KeyError at /
> 'daily'

and the line having mistake is shown to be

> >>>for daily_data in forecast_response['daily'][:5]:

In the for loop for `daily_forecast`s, I'm encountering a KeyError related to the 'daily' key in the OpenWeatherMap API response. I've verified my API key and the overall structure of the response, but I seem to be missing something crucial.

Please fix this it says that daily is not there but it is there.

Comment: Clearly you don't have a 'daily' in your JSON.  The json you received shows that you dont' have a valid API key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering suggests that the `daily` key is not present in the `forecast_response` dictionary. And according to the response, it shows that your `API` key is invalid, so you need to verify your `API`. To address this issue in the future, you should always check the `status_code` of your requests.

Below is an improved version of your code to handle this more gracefully.

```py
def fetch_weather_and_forecast(city, api_key, current_weather_url, forecast_url):
    current_weather_response = requests.get(current_weather_url.format(city, api_key))

    if current_weather_response.status_code != 200:
        # Handle error in the current weather response
        print(f"Error in current weather API request. Status code: {current_weather_response.status_code}")
        return None, []

    response = current_weather_response.json()

    lat, lon = response['coord']['lat'], response['coord']['lon']

    forecast_response = requests.get(forecast_url.format(lat, lon, api_key))

    if forecast_response.status_code != 200:
        # Handle error in the forecast response
        print(f"Error in forecast API request. Status code: {forecast_response.status_code}")
        return None, []

    forecast_response = forecast_response.json()

    weather_data = {
        'city': city,
        'temperature': round(response['main']['temp'] - 273.15, 2),
        'description': response['weather'][0]['description'],
        'icon': response['weather'][0]['icon'],
    }

    daily_forecasts = []
    
    # Check if 'daily' key is present in the forecast response
    if 'daily' in forecast_response:
        for daily_data in forecast_response['daily'][:5]:
            daily_forecasts.append({
                'day': datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(daily_data['dt']).strftime('%A'),
                'min_temp': round(daily_data['temp']['min'] - 273.15, 2),
                'max_temp': round(daily_data['temp']['max'] - 273.15, 2),
                'description': daily_data['weather'][0]['description'],
                'icon': daily_data['weather'][0]['icon'],
            })
    else:
        # Handle the case where 'daily' key is not present in the forecast response
        print(f"Error: {forecast_response['message'}")

    return weather_data, daily_forecasts
```

This modification includes checking the `status_code` before attempting to parse the `JSON` response for both the current weather and forecast `APIs`. It prints error messages with the status code if the requests are not successful.

So confirm your forecast `API` key, make sure it is correct and active, then try again with the improved code above.

Comment: Hello @Temi thanks for viewing my problem ,but this time when i run the code it just reloads the site and i have checked api its working but it it only reloads the site

Comment: Can you please check if any error printed out in the console?

Comment: no it does not show any error

Comment: Means everything is working well, can you share the views.py where the fetch_weather_and_forecast is called?

Comment: at this time stack overflow is not allowing to edit due to so many pending edits so i have added it into github repo please view it from here ->>>https://github.com/akshaydubey05/Weather_App_Django/blob/main/views.py

Comment: Okay seen, can you please confirm that you're sending a POST request, you can check your console and see that is a POST or GET request. IS there a form on the index page that you submit? If you could also add the html file to the repo so I can also check that for you.

Comment: yes i have uploaded the index.html and the other one too.

Comment: now in console this error shows up ->>>>Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received

Comment: So I tested this, you are still getting, Error in forecast API request. Status code: 401, did you check your forecast API key?

Comment: The weather requests seems to be fine, but forecast is still returning a 401 status_code. Maybe you can use a new API key, the issue is with the API key. Keep an eye on your console, if the page just refreshes then there is an error which you will see in your Django server console

Comment: ok i will see thanks for giving your time @Temi